# What kind of weed is this?

Tags: identification

[image] can someone please identify this weed. Thanks

Comment: This looks like the kind of grass in my lawn.  What part of the world are you located in?  What does the rest of the lawn look like that you feel this is a weed?

Comment: Looks like crab grass to me.

Comment: Depending on where you live, it's either crabgrass or quackgrass.

Comment: I live in San Antonio Tx.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Johnson Grass or Crabgrass or some sort of pasture grass... can't even start to ID grasses without seeing the flower/seed clusters.... also if it has rhizomes, what those look like can help.

Comment: What is the size of the plant?